# My WebApp (using facebook login) logs me out

Tags: facebook

I use the facebook Login on my website

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXX', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : 'XXX/channel.php', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      frictionlessRequests: true
    });

};
```

The problem is, I get logged out on my website every ~10-20min. The site it than reloading and I'm logged in again. I think the cookies gets deleted somehow.

Is there a way to make that cookie exist longer?

My login looks like that:

```
FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope:'publish_actions'});
```

**Update:**

This part of my script is called when a user logs in the first time:

```
// triggers on first login
if (isset($_GET['first_login'])) {
    if ($me) {
        $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
        $friends = $friends['data'];
        if (!empty($friends)) {
            // sql

        }
        $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");

        if( array_key_exists('publish_actions', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
            $attachment = array(
                    'message' => 'XXX',
                    'name' => 'XXX - App',
                    'link' => 'XXX',
                    'description' => 'XXX',
                    'picture'=> 'XXX',
                    'access_token' =>  $facebook->getAccessToken()
            );
            $facebook->api('/'.$facebook->getUser().'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);

            // sql
        }
        header('Location: http:/xxx');
    }
}
```

But I get an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#1) An error occured while
>   creating the share thrown in /facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1254

Which is caused by `$facebook->api('/'.$facebook->getUser().'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);`

When I remove the `link`-attribute from my `$attachment`, it works. Is the link attribute forbidden or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into extending facebook access tokens

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

however this uses the app secret so should not be done in javascript but in a server side language as well (possibly by combining your code with the php-sdk)

Comment: Thanks. I looked it up and I received the long-lived access token (which lasts 60 days). 
Do I have to store it in my database somewhere or is the user now logged in for 60days?

Comment: as per the docs it says "The response from this endpoint will include the long-lived access token. This will be a different string to the original token, so if you're storing these tokens, replace the old one." which to me implies you can store it in a cookie or elsewhere

Comment: Hi, I have to say you shouldn't be updating your question to ask a new question, especially after getting an answer . You should ask separate questions for different problems.Saying that the docs for posts are here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts and here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ what happens if you replace $facebook->getUser() with the string 'me'

Comment: Hm no, still getting the error. Nevermind, I will ask a new question. Thanks for your initial answer.

Comment: ok, how is your link formatted? Is it urlencoded does it include the http?