# Facebook setExtendedAccessToken() and FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login')

Tags: facebook

I'm currently developing my first facebook application. I have a problem with the setExtendedAccessToken() function in combination with FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login').

My js-code looks like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXX', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : 'http://domain.tld/app/channel.php', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      frictionlessRequests: true,
      cookie: true, 
      xfbml: true
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        $('#loginSpinner').show();
        $('#loginFacebook').hide();
        window.location = "http://domain.tld/app/?first_login";
    });      

};
```

The `auth.login` event should only trigger on the first login of the user.
This PHP Codes should also only trigger on the first login:

```
// triggers on first login
if (isset($_GET['first_login'])) {
    if ($me) {
        $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
        $friends = $friends['data'];
        if (!empty($friends)) {
        //sql
        }
        $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");

        if( array_key_exists('publish_actions', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
            $attachment = array(
                    'message' => 'XXX',
                    'name' => 'XXX - App',
                    'link' => 'http://domain.tld/app/',
                    'description' => 'XXX',
                    'picture'=> 'http://domain.tld/app/img.jpg',
                    'access_token' =>  $facebook->getAccessToken()
            );
            $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);

            //sql
        }
    }
    header('Location: http://domain.tld/app/');
    exit;
}
```

The problem is an infinite loop which will always call the `auth.login`, because `setExtendedAccessToken()` will destroy the current session and facebook will login the user to my app automatically.

Is there a way to trigger `auth.login` only once? When I set `setExtendedAccessToken()` as a comment

```
// $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
```

my site only redirects the users once as it should be. But I need the extended login for my app.

My previous question: [My WebApp (using facebook login) logs me out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839713/my-webapp-using-facebook-login-logs-me-out)

Answer (score 2):

Well then why don't you do this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        //it will only redirect if the token expires in less than 02h13m20s
        if(response && response.authResponse.expiresIn < 8000){
        $('#loginSpinner').show();
        $('#loginFacebook').hide();
        window.location = "http://domain.tld/app/?first_login";
        }
    });
```